# How to make complex json data with go struct?

Tags: json, api, go, struct

I want to build a json like

```
{
  "data": {
      "posts": [
        {"title": "first", "body": "first body"},
        {"title": "second", "body": "second body"}
      ],
      "categories": [
        {"name": "red"},
        {"name": "white"}
      ]
  }
}
```

It includes two parts of data: post and category. They are different structure. But want to send them together one time.

With this code

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type Article struct {
    Data struct {
        Post []struct {
            Title string `json:"title"`
            Body  string `json:"body"`
        } `json:"posts"`
        Category []struct {
            Name string `json:"name"`
        } `json:"categories"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        article := &Article{}
        data := article.Data

        post := data.Post
        post[0].Title = "first"
        post[0].Body = "first body"
        post[1].Title = "second"
        post[1].Body = "second body"

        category := data.Category
        category[0].Name = "red"
        category[1].Name = "white"

        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, article)
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8008"))
}
```

I tried to make a root struct `Article`, then define its children, then set data to tree one by one.

When run the server and call / endpoint, got error

```
echo: http: panic serving [::1]:49501: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0
goroutine 35 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc00012afa0)
    /Users/user/.goenv/versions/1.15.7/src/net/http/server.go:1801 +0x147
panic(0x1314380, 0xc00001a200)
    /Users/user/.goenv/versions/1.15.7/src/runtime/panic.go:975 +0x47a
main.main.func1(0x139b160, 0xc000208000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/user/test/testecho/server.go:28 +0x13b
github.com/labstack/echo/v4.(*Echo).add.func1(0x139b160, 0xc000208000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/user/go/1.15.7/pkg/mod/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.2.0/echo.go:536 +0x62
github.com/labstack/echo/v4.(*Echo).ServeHTTP(0xc000180000, 0x1397680, 0xc000200000, 0xc000072000)
    /Users/user/go/1.15.7/pkg/mod/github.com/labstack/echo/v4@v4.2.0/echo.go:646 +0x187
```

Then tried this

```
e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
    article := &Article{
        Data: struct{
            "Post": {
                {
                    "Title": "first",
                    "Body":  "first body",
                },
                {
                    "Title": "second",
                    "Body":  "second body",
                },
            },
            "Category": {
                {
                    "Name": "red",
                },
                {
                    "Name": "white",
                },
        },
    }
    a, err := json.Marshal(article)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, a)
})
```

But the `Data: struct{` line got `expected expression`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the code required by declaring a named type for each object in the output:

```
type Post struct {
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Body  string `json:"body"`
}

type Category struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Data struct {
    Posts      []Post     `json:"posts"`
    Categories []Category `json:"categories"`
}

type Article struct {
    Data Data
}
```

With this change, it's easy to write the composite literal:

```
article := &Article{
    Data: Data{Posts: []Post{
        {
            Title: "first",
            Body:  "first body",
        },
        {
            Title: "second",
            Body:  "second body",
        },
    },
        Categories: []Category{
            {
                Name: "red",
            },
            {
                Name: "white",
            },
        },
    },
}
```